# overflow error on the right by 2.9 pixels?

Tags: flutter, dart, layout

As you can see I have a custom card and I get this overflow error to the right. I tried fixing it by changing some of width, media query so its compatible with different screens. But couldn't figure why it's behaving like that. any help would be appreciated.
please check the code for the card I made below.

```
   `import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    class CustomerInfoCard extends StatelessWidget {
        final String mtrCity;
         final String ctymName;
        final String mtrNum;
        final String cusmName;
       final String mtrMNum;
       final String readingDate;
       final String posX;
       final String posY;
       final String faz;
        final String smart;
        final String address;

   final String billNum;
   final VoidCallback? onTap;

   const CustomerInfoCard(
      {Key? key,
      required this.mtrCity,
      required this.ctymName,
      required this.mtrNum,
      required this.cusmName,
      required this.mtrMNum,
      required this.readingDate,
      required this.posX,
       required this.posY,
      required this.faz,
     required this.smart,
     required this.address,
     required this.billNum,
     required this.onTap})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

   return Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
      child: Column(
       crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
       children: [

      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          color: Colors.white,
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5),
              spreadRadius: 5,
              blurRadius: 7,
              offset: Offset(0, 3),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 10, 5),
        height: size.height*0.25,
        width: size.width*5,
        child: GestureDetector(
          child: SizedBox(
            width: size.width*12,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                            child: Text(
                              "رقم الاشتراك",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: size.width * 0.04,
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontFamily: "Arabic",
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                            child: Text(
                              mtrNum,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: size.width * 0.04,
                                color: Colors.blue,
                                fontFamily: "Arabic",
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          child: Text(
                            "اسم المشترك:",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: size.width * 0.04,
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontFamily: "Arabic",
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          child: Text(
                            cusmName,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: size.width * 0.04,
                              color: Colors.blue,
                              fontFamily: "Arabic",
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          child: Text(
                            "رقم العداد:",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: size.width * 0.04,
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontFamily: "Arabic",
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          child: Text(
                            mtrMNum,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: size.width * 0.04,
                              color: Colors.blue,
                              fontFamily: "Arabic",
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          child: Text(
                            "الفاز:",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: size.width * 0.04,
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontFamily: "Arabic",
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          child: Text(
                            faz,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: size.width * 0.04,
                              color: Colors.blue,
                              fontFamily: "Arabic",
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: size.width *0.08,
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          child: Text(
                            "ذكي:",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: size.width * 0.04,
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontFamily: "Arabic",
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          child: Text(
                            smart,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: size.width * 0.04,
                              color: Colors.blue,
                              fontFamily: "Arabic",
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          child: Text(
                            "الموقع:",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: size.width * 0.04,
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontFamily: "Arabic",
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          child: Text(
                            address,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: size.width * 0.04,
                              color: Colors.blue,
                              fontFamily: "Arabic",
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: onTap,
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                            child: Text(
                              "عدد الفواتير:",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: size.width * 0.04,
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontFamily: "Arabic",
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                            child: Text(
                              billNum,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: size.width * 0.04,
                                color: Colors.blue,
                                fontFamily: "Arabic",
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    // Add more UI elements using the provided parameters
                  ],
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: size.width * 0.12,
                    height: size.height * 0.12,
                    // child: AvdPicture.asset('asset/${eximage[index]}'),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),

        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}
}
`

here is where I'm using it

```
 if (PhotoMeter != null)
            Visibility(
              visible: listvVisibility,
              child: Expanded(
                  child: CustomerInfoCard(
                mtrCity: PhotoMeter!.MTR_CITY,
                ctymName: PhotoMeter!.CTYM_NAME,
                mtrNum: PhotoMeter!.MTR_NUM,
                cusmName: PhotoMeter!.CUSM_NAME,
                mtrMNum: PhotoMeter!.MTR_M_NUM,
                readingDate: '',
                posX: '',
                posY: '',
                faz: PhotoMeter!.FAZ,
                smart: smart,
                address: '',
                billNum: '${invoicess.length}',
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/bills_info',
                    arguments: {
                    'invoicess': invoicess,
                  },);
```

[image]

Comment: The issue must be in your parent class where you're using `CustomerInfoCard` as i copied paste your widget code and it's working as expected. Can you provide the code for your parent class